# angular ngRoute breaks when using base tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? I put up a simple webpage to show you: http://plnkr.co/edit/TkADpfgchYVdvNTqRPFT?p=preview

I'm using base tag with a sub dir along with html5mode and the beta version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're really doing anything wrong.  I think its a bug in the new release candidate.  You're not really even doing anything special.  Its just in your `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` call.  That function calls angular's `beginsWith` function, which calls `.indexOf` on the url string, which is apparently `undefined`.  I would suggest creating a bug for it on angular's github page.  You can do that [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues?state=open).  I would simply post this issue and the link to your plunker and they should be able to handle it.

That's precisely why they ask us to test the rc's.  Good find.  I'm not actually using HTML5Mode, so I hadn't found this particular bug yet.

Comment: That is what i thought.. unfortunately :(

Comment: Just at a glance, it might also be related to this bug here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3511

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to call a method of an undefined variable. You should probably add a check such as:

```
if (typeof variable ==="undefined")
```

Comment: Its really not my issue, it's something angular team is doing